# Overriding configuration options for unattended-upgrades

Tags: apt, server, unattended-upgrades

I have several Ubuntu servers which I want to have all upgrades applied automatically. I used to use a simple script which ran `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` but that wasn't very robust, so I'm trying to migrate to `unattended-upgrades` instead, which seems to be the officially recommended way of doing this.

However, I'm struggling to achieve the following tasks:

- How to get an email every day (assuming `unattended-upgrades` runs every day). At the moment I only seem to get emails when packages are upgraded (I prefer to get an email every day as that way I know if the email doesn't arrive, something has gone wrong).
- How to upgrade all packages, not just those with security updates.

All the tutorials I can find, including the [official Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html), tell me to edit the existing files in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`. However, I prefer to override options using additional files, partly so that I don't get a 'configuration file differs from maintainer' error later and also because this makes it easier to keep all the overrides in configuration management and version control.

Is it possible to override all the configuration options in this way? I've tried doing this and have found that some overrides seem to work whilst others don't.

My current overrides files is at `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99zz-overrides` (named to make sure it's read last) and contains the following:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "hello@example.org";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

I haven't changed anything else in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`.

Comment: if you have setup notification to root email, what the output of `cat /var/mail/root`?

Comment: You may also need `APT::Periodic::Enable "1";` if not otherwise set

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri Emails get forwarded off the machine automatically, so there's nothing in `/var/mail/root`.

Comment: what the mail application you have? a `sendemail` package or a `apticron` package like on your link!

Comment: The problem is not with outgoing email, that works fine when `unattended-upgrades` sends an email. One of the issues I'm having is getting `unattended-upgrades` to send an email daily.

Comment: This should be two separate questions

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to:

- use `unattended-upgrades`
  **and**
- to change its behaviour
  **and**
- not to change the package scripts inside `unattended-upgrades` themselves

(so basically have your cake and eat it too **;-)** )

You'll have to:

- cron a daily script
- that [`grep`s today's date in `var/log/dpkg.log`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286740/how-to-select-today-date-in-a-file-with-cat-and-grep)
- sends you an email every day

if the email is empty: nothing happened, otherwise you'll have the log so all the empty and full emails together is what you asked for.

Comment: Or am I misunderstanding what you're trying to do here?

Comment: What I want to do is *override* the options used by `unattended-upgrades` (that are provided by the package maintainer), in the same way as I do for other pieces of software such as nginx, PHP etc.

Comment: You cannot do that without changing its config files unless you use the methodology above.  If you don't use the above, an upgrade to the `unattended-upgrades` package *might* ask for manual intervention.  If that's acceptable, I can change my answer.  If that's not acceptable, the above is the best I can do.

Comment: In that case it sounds like `unattended-upgrades` isn't for me then. Editing the files supplied by the package is a nightmare for configuration management and later upgrades and I've been burnt by that in the past (e.g. with sshd).

Comment: Like I said: you'd need to externalize of you do want to use `unattended-upgrades` or go back to your original script and make it more robust.  (As this is a Q&A site: that's all the information I have so all the information I can supply) @pwaring *[Answer edited](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1099226/revisions)*

Answer (score 0):

Drawing from https://gist.github.com/roybotnik/b0ec2eda2bc625e19eaf and https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades:

The file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` contains all the options available for its configuration and an explanation of each.

There does not seem to an option to send an email each time it is run, only when there are upgrades or problems. You can, however, set whether you want emails for all upgrades, or only problems (`Unattended-Upgrade::MailOnlyOnError ["true"/"false"]`

To answer the second part of your question, you can set the sources that unattended-upgrades will use as follows:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};
```

By uncommenting the `updates` or other lines, you would automatically update those corresponding sets of packages.